# ESP32 Wroom 32d minimal circuit

Tags: schematics, esp32

Trying to build a Wifi driven motor controller using ESP32 Wroom32d to control SSR. The following is the schematic have come up with. [image]
Apologies @jsotola, wanted to check with the community if the schematic is ok.

Comment: please add a clear, answerable question to your post.

Comment: add `IO0` and `EN` to the UART header so you can do automated programming (eg using ESP-Prog or equivalent)